# Lost Additional "Key&Value" parameters from Sitecore Presentation details Rendering on changing its template

Tags: sitecore-client

I lost Additional "Key&Value" parameters while changing its template from "Configure" ribbon in Sitecore 8.
 I have added Class in many rendering but when I change its Page template, all its key/value pair got lost.[image]

Do we have any setting that will keep Key/Value pair as is even we change the template?

Comment: Is this `Additional Parameters` field a custom field added by you? Have you added it to both templates manually or have you created a new template called `Template With Additional Parameters` and set this new template as base template for both templates?

Comment: these are not custom field , we can say these are rendering parameters those are available in each rendering in presentation details below "Additional Parameters" label

Comment: What did you select in new template? Is it the same or new one?

Comment: Not sure if those parameters would be saved. They probably should, but switching templates sometimes causes data lost if fields don't map to each other. A parameters template in this case would of probably prevented that. If you had two templates that used the same parameters template (which is the recommended way to do this) then you would have the values saved in theory since the fields would map.